# NoSuchKey in resize images using python on AWS (lambda + s3)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize images as soon as they are uploaded to s3.

I want that as soon as there is a PUT, a copy of it is made with the name `300x300_same_image_name.jpg` in the same bucket.

For that I created a lambda aws function and I was copying and updating some codes that I found from tutorials.

My code:

```py
import boto3
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import uuid
from io import BytesIO
import os


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    key = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
    size = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["size"]
    result_url = resize_image(os.environ["BUCKET"], key, size)
    response = {
        "statusCode": 301,
        "body": "",
        "headers": {
            "location": result_url
        }

    }
    return response


def resize_image(bucket_name, key, size):
    size_str = str(size)
    size_split = size_str.split('x')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Object(
        bucket_name=bucket_name,
        key=key,
    )
    obj_body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(obj_body))
    img = img.resize((int(size_split[0]), int(size_split[1])), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    buffer = BytesIO()
    img.save(buffer, 'JPEG')
    buffer.seek(0)
    resized_key = "{size}_{key}".format(size=size, key=key)
    obj = s3.Object(
        bucket_name=bucket_name,
        key=resized_key,
    )
    obj.put(Body=buffer, ContentType='image/jpeg')
    return resized_image_url(resized_key, bucket_name, os.environ["AWS_REGION"])


def resized_image_url(resized_key, bucket, region):
    return "https://s3-{region}.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/{resized_key}".format(bucket=bucket, region=region, resized_key=resized_key)
```

My problem: running the example (in aws function creation) I got this error:

```
Output: 
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.",
  "errorType": "NoSuchKey",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 15, in lambda_handler\n    result_url = resize_image(os.environ[\"BUCKET\"], key, size)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 35, in resize_image\n    obj_body = obj.get()['Body'].read()\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py\", line 520, in do_action\n    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py\", line 83, in __call__\n    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 316, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 635, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Looking for the web my line `obj_body = obj.get()['Body'].read()` seems ok. Does anyone have any light?

#### Solution

I understood my mistake. Using AWS tests there was no object. However running the function I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming from invalid S3 key. Print your key and verify if it exists there at all.

```py
obj = s3.Object(
   bucket_name=bucket_name,
   key=key,
)

obj.get()
```

Comment: Yep. This key not exists.

Comment: @JoeyFran OK, so you need to figure out why you try to reach not existing key.

Comment: I understood my mistake. Using AWS tests there was no object. However running the function I got it. Thank you.